# What is the power series of $1/(D-h(x))$ if $h(x)\ll D$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation, linear-approximation

I have a problem, which I do not conceptually understand. I need to approximate an arbitrary function

$$\frac{1}{D-h(x)}$$

where $h(x)$ is arbitrary, $h(x)\ll D$ and $D$ is a constant. Friends say to me that it is just equal to

$$\frac{1}{D-h(x)}\approx \frac{1}{D} \left(1+\frac{h(x)}{D}\right)$$

up to first linear term, which is basically a power series. I know that this would work for specific function where $h(x)=x$ and then the power series expansion would be

$$\frac{1}{D-x}\approx \frac{1}{D} \left(1+\frac{x}{D}\right),$$

but I do not see how we can just replace $x$ by $h(x)$.

Also, it seems that it is not possible to get expansion by using Taylor series if we use $h(x)$. Why power series would work and Taylor series not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is sufficient to consider the expansion of a *[geometric power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots\qquad\qquad|x|<1
\end{align*}
which is convergent for $|x|<1$.

The only crucial aspect here is the convergence criterion $|x|<1$, which enables us  to do a series expansion.

> When considering a function $h(x)$ with $\left|h(x)\right| \ll D$ we know that $\left|\frac{h(x)}{D}\right|<1$ and the geometric series expansion is admissible. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{D-h(x)}&=\frac{1}{D}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{h(x)}{D}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{D}\left(1+\frac{h(x)}{D}+\frac{h(x)^2}{D^2}+\cdots\right)\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $\left|h(x)\right| \ll D$ it follows that  higher powers of $\frac{h(x)}{D}$ are small and we can use the approximation
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{D-h(x)}\approx \frac{1}{D} \left(1+\frac{h(x)}{D}\right)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Note, that we do not require analytical properties of $h(x)$ in order to deduce (2). But *if* $h(x)$ is sufficiently often differentiable at $x=0$ we could also do a Taylor expansion in order to get (2).

Comment: Thank you! Ok, if we say that h(x) is differentiable, how we still can use Taylor series, because we do not know the derivative h'(x) because we do not know h(x) explicitly?

Comment: @AndrisErglis: Since we need for this approximation an expansion up to linear terms of  $h(x)$ only, we do not use the Taylor expansion. We just know that, if $h(x)$ is sufficiently often differentiable, an expansion as Taylor series is admissible, which might  be useful for some other analytical consideration. For the approximation we only need the fact that $|h(x)/D|<1$.

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks for the elaborate explanation!

Comment: @You're welcome. Note, that you can also upvote an answer indicating the content is useful.

Comment: Yes, I did, it just does not show it, because I still have not collected enough reputation :)

Comment: @AndrisErglis: Oh, I see. Many thanks for your nice reply.